# How to update the table contents which are displayed through jsp if some changes occur in SQL Server database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, jsp

I have a display page on which contents of the resultset are displayed.My database is continuously changing as real time values are inserted in it after every few minutes.Now I want my table which displays the data to be updated whenever there is change in the database or to be updated after every 30 minutes.I have used JSP for display,which calls a java class from where it retrieves the data from database.

For my solution , I have to hit the database again and again after every few minutes,if the contents of table do not match with database then I have to change the table data to reflect the changes .But how to implement this???Thanks in advance.

I have tried this,But nothing is being displayed only blank page is coming:-

```
<body>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function refreshFunction() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/BeanStatus.jsp', //page or method that will return html
      success: function(data) {
        $('div#loadData').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
window.setInterval(refreshFunction, 3000) </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. ..
Remove the script that you have, and refresh the whole page.

Add this to the head section of your page. The 30 in this case is 30 seconds....

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Comment: through this whole page will be refreshed after 30 seconds,but I want to refresh the table portion only.